# adding element to series with simple '.' notation

Tags: pandas, series

```
x = pd.Series()
x.a = 1
x.a
>> 1

x.values()
>>  array([])
```

x.a can be retrieved by calling it directly (x.a) but selecting a list of series elements doesn't include 'a'.
Is there a way to get a list of elements that does include 'a'.

Comment: I'd suggest you read the [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) docs, to understand why this fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not way to assign a new value by using `.`

```
x.loc['a']=1
x
Out[53]: 
a    1
dtype: int64
```